# Wowza media dash player not work on SSL pages

Tags: ssl, stream, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I use wowza media cache system to play test video from file on my website , wowza run on normal connection ( not SSL ) but my website run on SSL , than when I run test page by SSL , video not loaded and not played but when I run page without SSL video load and play.

I use sakak player and media dash system : https://github.com/google/shaka-player

I need add any config on wowza? or its player issues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Wowza server to be able to serve the manifest and stream over SSL. To configure from the Manager UI:

1. Select Server > Virtual Host Setup.
2. Click Edit > Add Host Port.
3. Enter your SSL port information, including the SSL certificate location and password.

Save your changes, and restart your Wowza services. You should be able to see that your server is listening on the configured SSL port. Do make sure that you have opened up this port in your server firewall.